# How to insert userstatus into friendlist?

Tags: sql, facebook

I am creating a wall like structure for my website in c# asp.net and sql server 2005.
I have created 2 tables : userstatus, friendlist.
When an user enters some value in his wall, it is inserted into userstatus.
Now, structure of friendlist table is [id],[usernames of friends].
I want that status to be inserted into all [usernames of friends] so that they can see it on there wall.
So, i want to know sql query about how to do this?

And suggestion to improve this.

Thanks in advance for helping,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is make any status update belongs to single user. When displaying posts for any user, query the status table by both your id and their friend's id.

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following query is pseudocode but should give you a start.

```
select userstatus.status 
from friendlist left join userstatus on friendlist.usernameoffriend = userstatus.username
where friendlist.username = current_user
```